# Azure Function does not connect to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I keep getting an error in application insight when trying to run my Azure function, it works locally on my computer but does not work in Azure. Here is the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.ResolveConnectionString

I have added CosmosDbTrigger as a connection string in the settings configurations, so I do not understand what's wrong. The function is triggered when a change is made in the cosmos db so if I change something in the db, and am running the function localy on my pc it works, It's only in the azure portal it keeps failing. The triggers are also working, so I think it's only the function that's the problem.

Comment: You should probably add some code to your question, minimal working example would be awesome. But going with just what you provided if it works locally and not when published, there is some problem with authentication. Check if the connection string present in cloud is valid.

Answer (score 1):

As there are many other discussions happening with similar issue from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1995) and check this [link](https://briandunnington.github.io/azure_functions_dynamic_connection_string) and try re checking your configuration file.

```cs
internal string ResolveConnectionString(string unresolvedConnectionString, string propertyName)
{
    // First, resolve the string.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unresolvedConnectionString))
    {
        string resolvedString = _configuration.GetConnectionStringOrSetting(unresolvedConnectionString);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to resolve app setting for property '{nameof(CosmosDBTriggerAttribute)}.{propertyName}'. Make sure the app setting exists and has a valid value.");
        }

        return resolvedString;
    }

    // If that didn't exist, fall back to options.
    return _options.ConnectionString;
}
```

Also, check your `_options.ConnectionString` value and set that dynamically.

```cs
builder.Services.PostConfigure<CosmosDBOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "dynamically set the connection string value here";
});
```

Comment: Hey Christine Garcia, has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: If the posted answer justifies your requirement, you may [mark it as the answer] by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Doing so can benefit other community members

Comment: I couldn`t make it work using isolated function